# Pop up with a random string of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, alert

I'm trying to make an alert box pop up with one random sentence from an array of sentences inside it. This is my code:

```js
var tasks = [
  "This is the first task",
  "And this is the second task",
  "Third task..."
];

var randomTask = Math.floor((Math.random() * tasks.length) - 1);

alert(tasks[randomTask]);
```

If you run it, the only thing the pop says is "undefined". Why doesn't it work?

Thanks to anyone that answers! :-)

Comment: Actually when (Math.random() * tasks.length) gives 1 then you are subtracting with 1 and then it should be 0 and the floor of 0 is -1. so when you accessing -1 property of array you are getting undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math.random` returns a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive), you multiply it by 3 and subtract 1, so you can get a number between -1 and 2 (where 2 is exclusive - value will always be lower than 2). And when you `floor` a negative value, you get -1. That's why you get undefined sometimes

Basically, remove `- 1` and it should work

Comment: Then can't I just remove the `-1`?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that, the `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1.

When the number is `0.1xxx`, it is

computed as

```
0.1xxxxx * 3 - 1
```

that is

```
Math.floor(0.3xxxx - 1) = -1
```

And `array[-1]` is  `undefined`.

To get around this issue, you can use `%` operator on the resulting random number. `%` will ensure that the number is always between `0` and `arr.length - 1`.

```js
var tasks = [
  "This is the first task",
  "And this is the second task",
  "Third task..."
];

var randomTask = Math.floor((Math.random() * tasks.length) % tasks.length);

alert(tasks[randomTask]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
var tasks = [
  "This is the first task",
  "And this is the second task",
  "Third task..."
];

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((tasks.length -1) - 0 + 1)) + 0;
alert(tasks[rand]);
```

Comment: How is `((tasks.length -1) - 0 + 1)` any different from `tasks.length`?

Comment: And why would you ever `+ 0` or `- 0`?